# How to remove dark black background from the loading spinner?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have made a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8F2Jkq?p=preview) and I want to remove the black background from the `ionicLoading` loading spinner. How could I achieve this?

```
var app = angular.module('newsapp', ['ionic']);


app.controller('newscontroller',function($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, $timeout){



   $scope.show = function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<img width="32" height="32" src="data:image/gif;base64,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">'
        }).then(function(){
            console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
        });
    };
    $scope.hide = function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
            console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
        });
    };

  $scope.news =[];

   $scope.show();

   $timeout(function () {
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=latest&apiKey=90b77760d33d4c76af4c6c53862c9e72"
      }).then(function(newsdata){
        angular.forEach(newsdata.data.articles, function(newsarticle) {
          $scope.news.push(newsarticle);
        });
         $scope.lastarticleID= newsdata.data.lastID;
         $scope.hide();
      })
   },
    2500);
});
```

Comment: Is this someting you want ? http://plnkr.co/edit/X80u5zEXGGmYcvn5OLpb?p=preview

Comment: Next time please click the `<>` to create a [mcve] HERE instead of trying to fool the SO editor into showing the link it told you it did not want to show

Comment: Well i did the search thats why i asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.loading{
  background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

Add this to your css... that will remove the dark black background from the loading spinner

Answer (score 2):

Override the CSS:

```
.loading {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You could delete it and get your rep back